# How can I force a metadata field to be treated as a hyperlink?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, hyperlink, metadata

We're using SP Foundation, and it should be assumed that we have no functionality apart from what comes OOTB.

We have a form we're creating that's basically a document index. One of the columns is a keyword, and another is the URL to which the keyword points.

Consider:

```
Keyword1     http://relativepath/Doc1.html
Keyword2     http://relativepath/Doc2.html
Keyword3     http://relativepath/Doc2.html
Keyword4     http://relativepath/Doc1.html 
Keyword5     http://relativepath/Doc3.html
```

I would like the list item to display both columns, but have the URL a clickable hyperlink. However, I can only get it to show up as a line of text, not a hyperlink.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a "Hyperlink or Picture" column type which will do what you want.

Comment: Awesome. I'll see if I can dig it up!